# How to Download Image From Url and Save It to a Local SQLite Database

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin, how do you download an image from a URL?

And then, how do you save the image to a local SQLite database on the device?

My Xamarin.Forms app currently follows the [Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Downloading_Images) to use a URL for the `ImageSource` property of an `Image`, and this works fine. But, I've noticed that every time the app launches, it re-downloads this image over the network. I'd prefer to download the image from the URL once and save it locally to the device; this method will save battery and data usage for the user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Explanation

To accomplish this, we'll download the image from the Url as a `byte[]` using `HttpClient`, then save it to our local SQLite database.

## Sample App

[Here is a sample app](https://github.com/brminnick/SaveImageToDatabaseSampleApp) that accomplishes this using Xamarin.Forms. For the best understanding, I recommend downloading the code from GitHub.

## Sample Code

#### Download Image From Url

We will download the image as a `byte[]` using `HttpClient`. This will make it easier to store it in our SQLite Database.

```
    const int _downloadImageTimeoutInSeconds = 15;
    readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_downloadImageTimeoutInSeconds) };

    async Task<byte[]> DownloadImageAsync(string imageUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var httpResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(imageUrl))
            {
                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Url is Invalid
                    return null;
                }
            }
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             //Handle Exception
             return null;
         }
    }
```

#### Save Model to Database

Once you've downloaded the image as a `byte[]`, we'll store it in the SQLite database.

I've added more information about the model in the next section.

```
public static async Task SaveDownloadedImage(DownloadedImageModel downloadedImage)
{
    var databaseConnection = await GetDatabaseConnectionAsync();
    await databaseConnection.InsertOrReplaceAsync(downloadedImage);
}
```

#### Model

In the model, I've created a property that stores the image as a string and a read-only property that returns the Image as a `Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource`.

```
public class DownloadedImageModel
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set;}

    public byte[] DownloadedImageBlob { get; set; }

    public ImageSource DownloadedImageAsImageStreamFromBase64String
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                if (DownloadedImageBlob == null)
                    return null;

                var imageByteArray = DownloadedImageBlob;

                return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageByteArray));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to save the image byte[] to a BLOB column under X* (vs converting to B64)?

Comment: Hi @Plutonix! I haven't played around with that method. Do you have sample code that shows how to do it? What are the Pros & Cons of using blob storage vs Base-64 strings?

Comment: In Winforms, using the NET provider it is like all other providers: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", DbType.Binary).Value = imgBytes` where the later is `byte[]`.  The downside to B64 is it is longer: 1140+ byte string to encode a 870 byte image.  Also, still in winforms, the provider can return an Image object to you so you dont have to decode it.  Saving images rather than a path to an archived image is generally a bad idea due to the bloat.  Maybe more so with SQLite

Comment: Good stuff! I didn't know that about the difference in byte-size. Do you have an example showing this in Xamarin? I'd love to check it out!

Comment: Don't use HttpClient in a using statement. Consider it a shared resource and reuse it as much as possible. Also be careful with loading large images into memory. Preferably you would save it to a file instead and just have the database point to the path instead.

Comment: Haha- you're spot on about HttpClient @Cheesebaron! I put the HttpClient in a using statement to keep this StackOverflow snippet succinct. In the sample app on GitHub, I follow best-practices; I reuse it and don't dispose it.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I updated my answer to reuse the HttpClient. Thanks again!

Comment: @Plutonix I finally got around to updating this Answer & the sample app to use byte[] instead of the Base-64 String. Thanks again for your recommendation!