# How to store byte array in sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am trying to store the files data in sqlite. Where i gets bytes of data

```
 public class FileDetailsEntity
{
    public byte[] FileStream { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

}
```

How to save `FileStream` in sqlite database.

I tried of using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.FileStream)` but it is showing encoding does not consists ASCII...is there any other way to store byte array[] in sqlite database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite how to declare as Byte Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280105/sqlite-how-to-declare-as-byte-array)

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560168/xamarin-forms-how-to-save-byte-to-sqlite-database